# using ajax to display a different php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
 <script>
 //jQuery('#frmSearch').click(function() {
 jQuery(function(){
 jQuery('#frmSearch').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();       
         jQuery.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'mutualfundsprices/do_price_archive.php',
             data: jQuery('#frmSearch').serialize(),
             success: function(data) {
                 jQuery('#DisplayResult').html(data);
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
 });
 </script>
```

the above is my JavaScript to display a different PHP page but after loading the result, the result disappears. 
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: show your markup, plz

Comment: you must be clearing it somewhere else..do you see the result appear? please show the full code..

Comment: try to insert a `console.log()` inside your success function to know the data value. Add also the `error` property inside the ajax method.

Comment: its displays result then the result disappers

Comment: thanks guys. i was actually clearing it in one of the codes. your info was great.

Answer (score 0):

I guess #frmSearch is a form on your DOM, right?

My guess is that the form is being submitted twice, once using your onclick function (ajax), and then the second may reload the page so that your AJAX-loaded HTML disappears. But I may be out of line here.

You are assigning an onclick, which is quite uncommon for forms. But still, e.preventDefault and return false; on an onclick event won't prevent the form to submitting if you ever click on the submit button. You might want to use the onsubmit event of the form instead, or, better yet, avoid having a submit button but rather have a normal button if you want to handle form submissions always using AJAX in your callback function.